# queryDSL: Fetch record by equating set element using Id

Tags: querydsl

I want to get the college_id based on the student_id, where `College` contains `Set<Student> students.`
I am querying like

```
@Query("SELECT clg.id FROM College clg WHERE clg.students.any() = (:student)")
public List<Object> getCollegeIdByStudent(@Param("student") Student student);
```

Passed in `student` instance contains only the primary key.
Exception thrown is

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.
```

Please suggest correct query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct query string should be something like

```
SELECT clg.id FROM College clg WHERE :student MEMBER OF clg.students
```

clg.students.any() is Querydsl syntax and can't be used in a JPQL query string.